# output row with recent date base on specific values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 5 columns. I need rows that have equal value on code, class_id and most recent date.

```
code        class_id            grade       date          class_name
7            48                   b          01/12/17      algebra
8            85                   a          07/28/08      calculus
10           50                   b          12/12/10      geometry
7            48                   c          07/10/19      history
23           48                   b          12/8/14       literature
8            85                   d          01/01/2020    economics
```

output

```
7            48                   c          07/10/19      history
8            85                   d          01/01/2020    economics
```

Comment: i have a dataframe with thousand of rows.thanks

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `string` date into `datetime` object, then do `groupby` and `merge`
Sample code is

```py
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%M/%y', errors='coerce', exact=False)
df2 = df.groupby(['code', 'class_id']).agg({
    'date1' : 'max',
    'grade' : 'count'
}).reset_index()
df2 = df2[df2['grade'] > 1].drop(columns=['grade'])
df2.merge(df, how='left', on=['code', 'class_id', 'date1'])
```

output of above code is as follows

```
   code  class_id               date1 grade        date class_name
0     7        48 2019-01-07 00:10:00     c    07/10/19    history
1     8        85 2020-01-01 00:01:00     d  01/01/2020  economics
```